# Image Transparency not working

Tags: windows-ribbon-framework

I am using Windows 8 RTM and Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop. I am trying to write an application that uses `UIRibbon` in Visual C++. (Because I have the Express version only, I don't have access to MFC; please don't use it in your answer.)

The problem has to do with the icons I use in the ribbon. Because Windows 7 compatibility is a requirement for this project, I cannot use PNG images; I am stuck with old-school BMPs. The problem is that, while some of the BMPs are displaying correctly, most of the images have black bounding-boxes around them. I suspect the problem has to do with the BMP files, and is not in the ribbon XML file or in the code.

The BMP that displays correctly I downloaded off the Internet as part of a sample that I adapted. The BMPs that don't display correctly I extracted from an ICO file, then converted to a 32-bit image using the `System.Drawing.Bitmap` .NET API. (This conversion process is in done in a separate program as part of my build procedure, not at runtime.)

My question is: Does changing the bit depth of a BMP in this manner affect the colors in the image? And, if so, can anyone point out a **free** tool that can turn a PNG file into a 32-bit BMP file that works correctly in the Windows `UIRibbon`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you speak of the [Windows Ribbon Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) here? If so, you wouldn't be able to use PNGs anyway as the framework supports BMP only for Windows 7. With Windows 8 you can also use PNGs. See the regarding M[SDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316921%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.

For a free tool which converts your PNGs into compatible BMP files, you should have a look at the visual designer that comes with the "[Windows Ribbon Framework for Delphi](http://www.bilsen.com/windowsribbon/index.shtml)".

You can simply load you XML markup into the editor and add your pictures. The editor will then convert the added files into BMPs if required. You can also use the editor to check if your Ribbon definition looks right. It produces valid "Windows Ribbon Framework" XML markup, so you can use the markup file in any other language such as C++, C# or Delphi for your further application development.